# Mylyn equivalent for Netbeans?

Tags: ide, netbeans, project-management, mylyn, task-management

A co-worker has been going on about how cool Mylyn is for Eclipse. I want to give a task management tool a try but I use Netbeans. **Is there a Mylyn like plugin for Netbeans? Preferable with integration to Redmine or Trac?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I switched over from Eclipse to Netbeans a year ago and during that time I have not found a good alternative to Mylyn. Even the latest dev builds of Cubeon do not come close. Despite Netbeans being a very good IDE, having Mylyn context management is essential to me. I have just posted a topic on the Netbeans forum discussing this issue and attempting to illustrate the importance of a Mylyn alternative. If this is important to anybody reading this then I suggest you leave a post in this thread:

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=27871

I think discussing this in the Forum is the best option at this time. Until the Netbeans community is convinced of the importance of Mylyn, any official feature request is doomed to fail.

Edit: There is now a feature request for this. If you would like to see this implemented then please vote here: http://code.google.com/p/cubeon/issues/detail?id=135

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Cube'n](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/cubentask-integration-netbeans), which is a Trac plugin for Netbeans.  I haven't used it (yet), but it has offline support, and some drag/drop integration with the task view, and support for custom trac workflows.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclosure: I am the creator of NBTaskFocus)

Now there is a plugin for Task-focused development (like Mylyn in Eclipse) in NetBeans IDE. Visit the NBTaskFocus project at [NBTaskFocus project page on Java.net](http://java.net/projects/nbtaskfocus)

This project currently provides local task repository only, but with automatic task context maintenance using the open editor windows and also a Project Context panel to see the files in focused context.

Comment: currently is outdated since -Nov 2011-, and is not working properly with NB 7.3

Comment: NBTaskFocus will be available for NetBeans IDE 8.0 from GitHUB

Answer (score 1):

I've used [cubeon](http://code.google.com/p/cubeon/) for couple of hours. The current latest version 1.2.01. is works fine on [Netbeans 7.2](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html). It can connect Trac servcer without any obstacle.

The UI of cubeon is little bit difficult to use. Main reason is that you should link a query to a folder with Synchronize Function to categories tasks. Also the filtering options hide under a drop down menu. It needs more mouse click than MyLyn in Eclipse. Any you can manage issues on Trac with this tool.